# What would be a reasonable way to gain attention of Phys. SE members on a question I posted in Math. SE?

Tags: discussion

I had to compute a Laurent series, and happened to obtain a correct result by certain manipulations that mathematicians (and even many physicists) would completely disapprove. I suspected that there must be a deeper reason for this, and asked it in Math. SE:

[An outrageous way to derive a Laurent series: why does this work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894704/an-outrageous-way-to-derive-a-laurent-series-why-does-this-work)

Then, in one of the comments, it has been brought up that physicists may have better insights to this kind of issue. I agreed with this suggestion, and considered posting the same question in Phys. SE; however, I thought it may be off-topic here.

I wonder what are other members' opinions on whether I should copy-paste this question to Phys. SE or leave it in Math. SE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best way to draw attention to a question on another site is to post a link in chat.

Making a meta post which happens to link to the question (as you did) also does achieve that result. But (for future posters) if there's nothing more to the post than "check out this question on another site," I don't think that's a good use of meta.

Comment: I didn't mean to use Phys. SE. Meta to achieve my purpose. I simply thought that it would be best to just show the question when asking whether it is something that can be posted in Phys. SE. As two of you pointed this out, I'll just delete the link.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to say you did something wrong this time - it's fine to have the link. I'm just saying that for people who might consider trying that in the future.

Comment: I see. Then I won't bother to explain what the question is in detail and delete the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Side note: There are certain cases (this is probably not one of them, as mentioned elsewhere, since it is *pure* math) where a question can be on topic on two different sites, and moreover the ways of looking at the question are significantly different between the two fields.

In such cases, once you have responses on one site you may want to post (a possibly reworded variant of) the question on a second site, in order to get a different perspective. However, you should make sure

1. It really is on topic on the site;
2. You are interested in different approaches, not just in having a different group of people verify what has already been done;
3. You link to the old question, so new answerers are aware of what has been said and don't duplicate any work.

In general, I would avoid cross-posting simultaneously; post once, get some feedback, then post somewhere else if warranted. Also note that it is all too easy to abuse cross-posting. If you only are looking for one answer, any answer, then pushing your query to multiple communities merely to improve the odds of getting an answer is frowned upon.

Note most of what I say here is for future visitors who come across this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If it has no connection to physics, it can stay where it is.

Just because some physicists are good at getting the right answers by the wrong means, this does not mean that we are the ones to ask for such means.

The [list of on-topics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (not an actual term) lists *pure mathematics* only in the presence of physics. If there's no physical motivation for what you want to compute and how you compute it, I would vote to migrate such a question to math.SE.

For the matter of drawing attention to your question on physics.SE, I believe you just achieved that

Comment: I see. I'll just keep it in Math. SE.